# Javascript perform every with nested includes

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

I have the following data:

```
selectedProducts = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
```

Upon clicking on checkboxes. I want to show all options associated to those selected products. I am doing this:

```
const hasSelectedProducts = this.selectedProducts.every(product =>
  dealer.products.includes(product)
);
```

The problem is that I am only checking for only one product, and not multiple products. How can I check for all selected products? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you are only checking for one product?

Comment: `Every` will give you a boolean value (true/false), not what you're looking for in here.

Comment: [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: And I think what you need is [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `every`. Or [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Choose your pick.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments! You are all correct. I will go with `map` or `filter`, but once I mapped or filtered the products how can I make `dealer.products = ["Saab", "Volvo"]`

Comment: I need to check that those products are included in `dealer.products`